# Calls to endpoints doubles each login/logout in React Native

Tags: react-native, redux-saga

Each time I dispatch some action and have a call to an endpoint on a particular screen I got one call after the first login in React Native. When I logout and login again and go to the screen with this dispatch action I got call to this endpoint doubled (as I see from Flipper). So after the 4 or 5 login/logout I get 8 or 16 calls to one endpoint. I use Redux Saga as middleware.

The problem is in this helper function for sagas to cancel all tasks on Logout

```
function* takeCancelableLatest(actionType, saga, parentSaga) {
  const task = yield takeLatest(actionType, saga);

  yield take(AppActions.LOGOUT);
  yield cancel(task);

  yield take(UserActions.SET_TOKENS);
  yield spawn(parentSaga);
}

export { takeCancelableLatest };
```

Function usage:

```
export function* itemsGetAllSaga() {
  yield all([
    takeCancelableLatest(itemsGetAll, itemsGetAllWorker, itemsGetAllSaga),
    takeCancelableLatest(itemsGetAllCommit, itemsPaginationWorker, itemsGetAllSaga),
  ]);
}
```

Comment: can you provide an example of your code?

Comment: @KirillNovikov I have added the problem code that causes this loop

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found the error and solution.
the problem was in yield spawn(parentSaga); in helper function